# Submit form - cach after submited

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to post the form from modal. To keep the current page, I target post to the iFrame.

Which trigger is triggered after posting the form? Or any other solution to close modal after post?
OnSubmit, as seen in the code, do not work.

```
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form method="post" id="modalForm" action="/Test/TestForm" target="myframe">
                <input type="text" name="id" required />
                <input type="text" name="name" required />
                <input type="submit" value="Post" onsubmit="alert('after post - close modal!');" />
            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: Given the code, I would guess the iframe onload event (and to give you something to work on until some can provide a definitive answer).  The alternative would be to use ajax to $.post to your server.  `onsubmit` runs before the submit occurs (so you can cancel it eg if the form is not valid / incomplete)

Answer (score 0):

You can post form via `Ajax` and get the begin and end request by using the following approach:

```
<script> 
    $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        //display loading, etc.
    });

    $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
        //hide loading, etc.
    });        
</script>
```